# SQL-DateAdded Function and Sum issue

Tags: sql-server, sum, case, dateadd

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    p.name as Name, SUM(r.attempts) as Attempts, SUM(r.gains) as Positive,       
    SUM(r.losses) as Negative, SUM(r.yards) as Net, SUM(r.touchdowns) as TD,
    SUM(r.longest) as Long, year(g.date_) as Season 
FROM 
    Rush AS r 
INNER JOIN                
    PlayerGame AS pg ON r.playerGame_Id = pg.playerGame_Id 
INNER JOIN 
    Players AS p ON p.player_Id = pg.player_Id
INNER JOIN 
    Games as g ON g.game_Id = pg.game_Id 
WHERE
    g.date_ LIKE CASE 
                    WHEN month(g.date_) = 1 
                       THEN DATEADD(year, -1, g.date_)
                    ELSE g.date_ 
                 END
GROUP BY
    year(date_), name
ORDER BY 
    Season DESC, Attempts DESC, Positive, Negative, Net, TD, Long
```

I am attempting to get the summation of all the stats from each season. I am trying to add all the extra games played in January for a full season. When I run this query, the seasons are separate with the January dates. However, for all the games played in January, it does not add them to the sum of all the attempts, yards, etc. If anyone could help or if you need extra context let me know. Thanks

Comment: you mean that your season start feb and end  jan ?

Comment: Yes, in essence

Comment: You would need to repeat the 'CASE' logic that you have.  However, from a long term perspective, I would have a seasons table as I will outline in my answer

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using SSMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a  year with a substracted  month 
this for mysql

```
SELECT p.name as Name, SUM(r.attempts) as Attempts, SUM(r.gains) as Positive,       
SUM(r.losses) as Negative, SUM(r.yards) as Net, SUM(r.touchdowns) as TD,
SUM(r.longest) as Long, year(DATE_SUB(date_,INTERVAL 1  MONTH)) as Season 
FROM Rush AS r INNER JOIN                
PlayerGame AS pg ON r.playerGame_Id = pg.playerGame_Id 
INNER JOIN Players AS p ON p.player_Id = pg.player_Id
INNER JOIN Games as g ON g.game_Id = pg.game_Id 

Group by year(DATE_SUB(date_,INTERVAL 1  MONTH)), name
Order by Season DESC, Attempts DESC, Positive, Negative, Net, TD, Long
```

This for sql-server

```
SELECT p.name as Name, SUM(r.attempts) as Attempts, SUM(r.gains) as Positive,       
SUM(r.losses) as Negative, SUM(r.yards) as Net, SUM(r.touchdowns) as TD,
SUM(r.longest) as Long, year(DATEADD(month, -1, date_)) as Season 
FROM Rush AS r INNER JOIN                
PlayerGame AS pg ON r.playerGame_Id = pg.playerGame_Id 
INNER JOIN Players AS p ON p.player_Id = pg.player_Id
INNER JOIN Games as g ON g.game_Id = pg.game_Id 

Group by year(DATEADD(month, -1, date_)), name
Order by Season DESC, Attempts DESC, Positive, Negative, Net, TD, Long
```

Comment: it is telling me that DATE_SUB is not a built in function

Comment: which db you are using?

Comment: I am using SSMS

Comment: i have add  version for sql-server too hope is useful

Comment: It still isn't adding the sums of each stat together

Comment: yuo want the stat distinct for season  or you need  all the total for all the seasons ?

Comment: Distinct for season

Comment: group by year(DATEADD(month, -1, date_))  mean season ...  please explain better ..

Comment: It is working, there was syntax error, thank you so much.

Comment: yes  ...but using  year(D ATEADD(month, -1, date_) should return a  season starting form feb and ending with jan

Answer (score 0):

Create a table `Seasons` with columns `Season`, `SeasonStart` and `SeasonEnd`.

```
SELECT p.name as Name, SUM(r.attempts) as Attempts, SUM(r.gains) as Positive,       
SUM(r.losses) as Negative, SUM(r.yards) as Net, SUM(r.touchdowns) as TD,
SUM(r.longest) as Long, s.Season as Season 
FROM Rush AS r INNER JOIN                
PlayerGame AS pg ON r.playerGame_Id = pg.playerGame_Id 
INNER JOIN Players AS p ON p.player_Id = pg.player_Id
INNER JOIN Games as g ON g.game_Id = pg.game_Id 
INNER JOIN Seasons AS s on g.date_ BETWEEN s.SeasonStart AND s.SeasonEnd
Group by s.Season, name
Order by s.Season DESC, Attempts DESC, Positive, Negative, Net, TD, Long
```

Then the need for special date logic goes away and is represented by the table.